# Error using segminopt>segminoptmpl No convergence achieved within maximum number of iterations

Tags: matlab, svm

I have problem to using SVM Classifier when i extracted the features from train data  (13393 of images) and from test data  (5740 of images) i use these code:

```
model_svm = svmtrain(Feature_Train,trainingLabels,'ShowPlot',true);
predictedLabels = svmclassify(model_svm, Feature_Test,'showplot',true);
```

Where the Feature_Train is a matrix of 13393x4096  and  Feature_Test is a matrix of 5740x4096 But this error show:

```
Error using segminopt>segminoptmpl (line 198)
No convergence achieved within maximum number of iterations 
Error in segminopt (line 81)
[alphas offset] = segminoptImpl(data, targetLabels,....
Error in svmtrain (line 503)
[alpha bias] = segminopt(training, groupIndex,....
```

What can I do to fix the error? Please advise me

Comment: this can be because of the data and there may not be anything to do

Comment: what do you mean? how that this be because of the data?